# How to backup a folder once a day?

Tags: backup

I use an instantaneous cloud service (dropbox), but If mess up with a file, dropbox will sync it anyway. So, how to backup a file/folder to another folder once a day?

(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Short answer: cronjob with rsync command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` is the way to go when doing these sort of things, with a little help from `cron` to schedule the task.

So for example, if you want to backup the directory `/foo/bar` recursively to remove server `spamegg`, you can do:

```
rsync -a /foo/bar user@spamegg:/where/to/put
```

`rsync` will do incremental backup so will not be network and bandwidth intensive too.

Setting this as a daily `cron` job, open your `crontab` by `crontab -e` and put:

```
00 02 * * * rsync -a /foo/bar user@spamegg:/where/to/put
```

This will run the `rsync` job daily at 02:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default "backups" (Deja-Dup).

But first, ensure that "duplicity" is installed:

`sudo apt-get install duplicity`